# Sharepoint 2010 auto-generated table structure for webpart

Tags: html, html-table, sharepoint-2010, rendering, web-parts

I'm using SP 2010. Whenever I insert a webpart in a webpart zone, Sharepoint injects a HTML table in the page and places my webpart in a cell of that table. This messes up my layout, since the CSS is created using class inheritance, and I end up having HTML tables in my source, which I don't need and I did not took into account.

Is there any way to change the way a webpart is rendered in the page? Any way to inform Sharepoint that I don't need that extra structure to be added in my page?

Comment: Not an easy way. Sharepoint still loves tables even in the newest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can add webparts directly to a Page Layout and you will get more control over the resulting HTML.  I'm not sure if this is an option for your situation, but if you put the webparts directly in your page layout and not into a web part zone then you will avoid some of the extra tables that SharePoint inserts.

Comment: It's an ideea, but unfoturnattly I cannot use it because I need to allow users to add or remove those webparts to my page.

Comment: plus, adding web-parts directly to the page, adds a whole bunch of spaghetti code